# change install location of files in rpm generated with cpan2rpm

Tags: perl, rhel8

I am trying to generate RPMs with `cpan2rpm` command.

The generated rpm places files in `/usr/local/share/perl5` instead of `/usr/share/perl5`.

cpan2rpm [help](https://metacpan.org/release/BBB/cpan2rpm-2.028_04/view/cpan2rpm) doesn't seem to mention any option to do this.

Is it possible to change the location to `/usr/share/perl5`

command used

```
cpan2rpm --version 0.27 --release 1000000000.el8 --debug=1 --packager=XXXXXXX --distribution=unknown --author XXXXXXX (unknown) --no-sign Catalyst-Plugin-Session-0.40.tar.gz
```

perl version 5.26

as suggested in comments, I had configured the environment variable

```
export PERL_INSTALL_ROOT=/usr/share/perl5
```

but still the files are being generated to `/usr/local/share/perl5`

```
$ rpm -qlp /output/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session-0.40-1000000000.el8.noarch.rpm
/usr/local/share/man
/usr/local/share/man/man3
/usr/local/share/man/man3/Catalyst::Plugin::Session.3pm
/usr/local/share/man/man3/Catalyst::Plugin::Session::State.3pm
/usr/local/share/man/man3/Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Store.3pm
/usr/local/share/man/man3/Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Store::Dummy.3pm
/usr/local/share/man/man3/Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Test::Store.3pm
/usr/local/share/man/man3/Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Tutorial.3pm
/usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst
/usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst/Plugin
/usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst/Plugin/Session
/usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst/Plugin/Session.pm
/usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst/Plugin/Session/State.pm
/usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst/Plugin/Session/Store
/usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst/Plugin/Session/Store.pm
/usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst/Plugin/Session/Store/Dummy.pm
/usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst/Plugin/Session/Test
/usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst/Plugin/Session/Test/Store.pm
/usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst/Plugin/Session/Tutorial.pod
/usr/share/doc/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session
/usr/share/doc/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session/Changes
/usr/share/doc/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session/README
/usr/share/doc/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session/inc
/usr/share/doc/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session/inc/Module
/usr/share/doc/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session/inc/Module/Install
/usr/share/doc/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session/inc/Module/Install.pm
/usr/share/doc/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session/inc/Module/Install/AuthorTests.pm
/usr/share/doc/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session/inc/Module/Install/Base.pm
/usr/share/doc/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session/inc/Module/Install/Can.pm
/usr/share/doc/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session/inc/Module/Install/Fetch.pm
/usr/share/doc/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session/inc/Module/Install/Makefile.pm
/usr/share/doc/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session/inc/Module/Install/Metadata.pm
/usr/share/doc/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session/inc/Module/Install/Win32.pm
/usr/share/doc/perl-Catalyst-Plugin-Session/inc/Module/Install/WriteAll.pm
```

Comment: have you tried setting PERL_INSTALL_ROOT=/usr/share/perl5

Comment: yes.  but even then the files are still being places in `/usr/local/share/perl5`